# ACF ordering by datetime field for upcoming events not working

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to pull a list of events that are upcoming in WordPress using the ACF DateTime picker field.

What I thought should be a relatively simple set of `$args` is now baffling me as to why it does not work:

```
$args = [
 "post_type" => "event",
 "post_status" => "publish",
 "posts_per_page" => 3,
 "order" => "ASC",
 "orderby" => "meta_value",
 "cat" => implode(',', $category),
 "meta_query" => [
   [
    "key" => "event_start_date_and_time",
    "compare" => ">=",
    "value" => date('U'),
    "type" => "DATETIME"
   ]
],
"meta_key" => "event_start_date_and_time",
"meta_type" => "DATE"
];
```

This is bringing through events but they are not all in ASC order of the start date time.

Am I missing something obvious?

Documentation

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-time-picker/

Database values

ACF DateTime Picker fields will store dates in the database like the following

`2018-07-21 15:00:00`

Comment: change meta_type with `DATETIME`

Comment: I have tried changing both to `DATETIME` and `DATE` and neither return the list I want.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working its tested code.

```
        $posts = array(
         "post_type" => "product",
         "post_status" => "publish",
         "posts_per_page" => 3,
         "order" => "ASC",
         "orderby" => "meta_value",
         "cat" => implode(',', $category),
         "meta_query" => (
         array (
            "key" => "evntdate",
            "compare" => ">=",
            "value" => date('U'),
            "type" => "DATETIME"
           )
        ),
        "meta_key" => "evntdate",
        "meta_type" => "DATETIME"
        );
        $posts=get_posts($posts);
```